# Route Redirect to another route before redirecting to actual route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

When you are already authenticated and  you enter login manually within the address bar it redirects you to login route before redirecting to the Dashboard,

for example localhost:3000/login will redirect to login before redirecting to localhost:3000/Dashboard

```
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/login">
              <Login />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/signup">
              <Signup />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/dashboard">
              <Dashboard />
            </Route>
           </Switch>
```

Comment: Is there a question or issue here? Can you clarify for us and if necessary, post a relevant [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: made some edit check it out my route

Comment: There still isn't a question.

Comment: What is the ***it*** doing the redirecting? There still isn't a question or [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Above is my route ,, but the problem is whenever I enter /login in the address bar when the user is authenticated, it redirect to login before redirecting to the dashboard